# How to make this a continuous vertical scroller? (jquery)

Tags: jquery, carousel, scroller

See this page:

http://www.laurensbeerten.be/Frames/FrameE.html

The first problem is that there is a "hickup" in the animation after a second or so.

The second problem is that once all images have been looped, it immediately starts again at the top, instead of it being continuous. Is there any way to change this?

I think I need to somehow clone a set of the images and attach that..

The code:

```
$(function() {
  var ticker = $('#ticker');
  function animator(currentItem, first) {                              
    if (first) {
      distance = 85;
    } else {
      distance = currentItem.outerHeight();
    }
    duration = (distance + parseInt(currentItem.css("marginTop"))) / 0.05;
    if (isNaN(duration)) {
      duration = 1200;
    }
    currentItem.animate({ marginTop: -distance}, duration, "linear", function() {
      currentItem.appendTo(currentItem.parent()).css("marginTop", 0);
      animator(currentItem.parent().children(":first"));
    });
  };
  animator(ticker.children(":first"), true);
  ticker.mouseenter(function() {
    ticker.children().stop();
  });
  ticker.mouseleave(function() {
    animator(ticker.children(":first"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have two JS fiddle's for you.

The first fixes your code http://jsfiddle.net/VCBXz/12/. The first problem was that you need to manipulate the container's margin not the current item. Secondly you need to detach and re-append the current item in the DOM so that the list is updated.

The second fiddle is using CSS3 http://jsfiddle.net/ca7Ef/4/. This way there is no code involved. Browser support might not be as good as jquery but it is something to consider.

Here is the updated javascript. Note that I changed your inner p tag to a div.

```
var ticker = $('#ticker');
var container = $('#ticker > div');
var spacing = ticker.outerHeight() - ticker.height();

function animator(currentItem) {
    var distance = currentItem.outerHeight() + spacing;
    var currentTop = parseInt(container.css('margin-top'), 10);
    var duration = (distance + currentTop) / 0.05;

    container.animate({ marginTop: -distance}, duration, "linear", function() {
        var parent = currentItem.parent();

        currentItem.detach();
        parent.css("marginTop", 5);

        parent.append(currentItem);
        animator(parent.children(":first"));
    });
};


animator(container.children(":first"));
ticker.mouseenter(function() {
    container.stop();
});

ticker.mouseleave(function() {
    animator(container.children(":first"));
});​
```

Comment: Sorry I realised there was a problem when the animation started and stopped from the mouse over. That is fixed now.